# Metro app references and types in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I developing C#\XAML metro-ui application. I need some .NET types that doesn't included in `.NET for Metro style apps` or `Windows` references (for instance [HttpUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx) that is located in `System.Web`). I can't find `System.Web` via Assembly List. In same time I can refer it via Browse. But as I understand correct isn't it good way and I should avoid this, is it?

Next thing I have found description of [Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.reflection.assembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Class. In the bottom of page in `Version Information` section I can see that it is supported by `Portable Class Library`. In the sample I see next code

`Assembly assem = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();`

But in my project `Assembly` doesn't have `GetExecutingAssembly` method. Is it documentation outdated? or I miss something?

I use Windows 8 Release Candidate and VS 2012

EDIT0: Instead of `HttpUtility` I should use `WebUtility` I know it. But I choose this type just for example.

EDIT1: I see `public static System.Reflection.Assembly GetExecutingAssembly()` via Object Browser but can't reach it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metro style apps can only call methods in the .NET Core Profile.  You can see the Core Profile reference assemblies on Windows 8 RP machine at ...

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5
```

You can use ILDasm or ILSpy to view them.  See [A .NET developer's view of Windows 8 app development](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-930C) video from Build.  He talks more about the Core Profile and why some classes, methods and interfaces were removed.

Comment: It is strange, but ILSpy shows that `Assembly` doesn't have `GetExecutingAssembly` but Object Browser in VS 2012 shows that has.

Comment: What about portable assemblies? They are located there - `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5`